# How to deploy a Google Cloud Function to an endpoint like /a/b

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I've two simple functions, one triggered by the endpoint `/root` and another triggered by the endpoint `/root/workflow`.

I use the following command to deploy `/root`:
`gcloud beta functions deploy root --stage-bucket ... --trigger-hhtp`

How can I deploy the second function with the endpoint `/root/workflow`?

Answer (score 0):

Definitively, it's not possible to do it. Function names can only contain numbers, letters and hyphens.

From Google Cloud Platform: *"Name must start with a letter followed by up to 47 letters, numbers, or hyphens, and cannot end with a hyphen"*.

If a proper API is needed and you would like a serverless solution, then [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) should be used. Also [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) and [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/) can have proper API definitions.

[Google Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) is the gateway powering the three solutions mentioned above.